# My ground is not lighting up

Tags: opengl

Im a bit stuck with my lighting. My light can light up meshes but it does not light up my ground.

Here is some of my code

The light:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);


GLfloat ambient_light0[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
GLfloat position_light0[] = { 0.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f, 0.9f };


GLfloat spotDirection_light0[] = {0.0, -1.0, 0.0 };
GLfloat specularLightcolor[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position_light0 );
glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spotDirection_light0 );
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 0.5);

glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient_light0 );
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specularLightcolor);

glLightf( GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 60.0f );
glLightf( GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 50.0f );
```

The ground:

```
void drawGround(int id) {

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);



getTexture(id);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id); 

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);



GLfloat material_diffuse[] = {0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0 };

    GLfloat material_specular[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };



glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, material_diffuse);

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, material_specular);


glBegin(GL_QUADS); 



for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){

    for(int j= 0; j<3; j++){

    glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, material_diffuse);

        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, material_specular);

        glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 80.0);



    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);

    glVertex3f(-floorSize +((j)*(2*floorSize)/3), 0 ,-floorSize +((i)*(2*floorSize)/3));

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);     

    glVertex3f(-floorSize +((j)*(2*floorSize)/3), 0 ,-floorSize +((i+1)*(2*floorSize)/3));

    glTexCoord2f(0,0);  

    glVertex3f(-floorSize +((j+1)*(2*floorSize)/3), 0 ,-floorSize +((i+1)*(2*floorSize)/3));

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);     

    glVertex3f(-floorSize +((j+1)*(2*floorSize)/3), 0 ,-floorSize +((i)*(2*floorSize)/3));


    }

}


glDepthMask( 1.0 );

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glEnd();

}
```

Drawing of the ground happens after the light is called.
Has anyone any idea why my ground is not lighting up?

here is a screen shot of my problem ---> [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, that default fixed function OpenGL lighting does the illumination at the vertices only, and then just interpolates the resulting color. Since all the 4 vertices of the ground are dimly lit, the whole quad gets dim.

Solutions:

- further subdivide your ground, so that there are more light sampling points. *So far you've got only 3×3 points, which is not nearly sufficient. Think 100×100 or even more, to get a nice illumination effect.*

or

- use a fragment shader to implement per pixel lighting.

You're running into a typical OpenGL newbie pitfall there, BTW.

<s>Update:</s>

On a side note: You also did not supply normals for the plane. Therefore lighting will not work at all.

Comment: doesn't glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); supply the normals?

Comment: @ettan: Of course it does. Silly me, I didn't notice it. However you cannot switch material parameters in a glBegin/glEnd block. My suggestion: Don't use immediate mode at all. Use vertex arrays.

Comment: I've subdivide the ground into 100x100, without any success. even tried 1000x1000 with no difference.

Comment: @ettan: Could you post your full sourcecode somewhere? At pastbin.com for example. I'd like to tinker with your code to find the problem.

Comment: @ettan: While you increased the number of tiles, you didn't reduce each tiles size, to the resolution, i.e. density didn't increase – after I did this, I got nice lighting. I fixed the code as far as possible: http://pastebin.com/dMjHqM6V I presume the whole thing was given to you (students) to fill with an exercise. Let me tell you this: This looks like some assistant was given the task to tutor some students; that guy did some Copy'n'Paste of tutorial code and filled it with his own misguided ideas about how those cogs fit. Personally I'd strongly question the quality of the course.

Comment: Thank you datenwolf. The fps counter was my little addon. thanks for the quick reply's.